# How to go about baking fine details into normals

Tags: normals, baking, subdivision-surface

I'm trying to sculpt pretty fine details into my model's normal map. The model is about 350 vertices, but for the detail I want I need to subdivide it a ton of times to not get ugly edges around the stuff I'm sculpting (I'm using the multiresolution modifier, but I've also tried with subdivision surface - 8x times seems to do it, 7x still has some roughness).

This gets me something like 20 million vertices in my high detail mesh, which seems to always crash Blender (EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION) when I try to bake normals. My specs are:

- Intel i7-9750H CPU @ 2.60GHz
- 16,0 Gt RAM
- GeForce RTX 2060

I've tried Blender 3.0 and 2.93, both keep crashing - with 7x subdivision the bake seems to work. Crash log is here: https://pastebin.com/75tRTLXy

I've tried:

- Baking with only CPU
- Baking with & without a cage
- Changing Windows' virtual memory settings
- Someone recommended setting tile size to the bake's target resolution & render samples to 16 for baking, tried that
- Tried different target resolutions
- Launched blender as admin

No dice so far.

These plant figures for instance get blurry with 7x (pic is with 8x):
[image]

How should I go about this; am I trying to brute force this with subdivisions, is there a better way? I know about dyntopo and would -love- to use it, but the layer brush doesn't seem to support it. Without the layer brush, continuing from one stroke to another leaves a dip where the two accumulate together, regardless of any settings I've found.

I figure ZBrush for instance could work better but I'd like to do as much as I can within one program.

Tried banging my head into this for a while now, getting the feeling I'm doing something wrong / in a really backwards way. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have any addons enabled that might interfere with the bake? (GoB addon, for example causes bakes to crash).

Comment: I tried disabling all addons except Cycles & Node Wrangler, still crashes. Since it works with 7x subdivisions, it might just be too much detail for my rig (is baking a 20mil vert mesh too much? I have little frame of reference here), but I have no idea how to approach this differently, besides just settling for jagged edges in my normals.

Comment: Have you tried applying the subdivision modifier before baking?  Easier on Blender to not have to compute subdivs on the fly.

Comment: Tried applying the subdivs before baking - still crashed. Cheers for the suggestion though!

Comment: Voxel remesh with the correct size (around 0.004 in my model's case) can reduce the vertex count low enough that the bake succeeds without lowering details too much. I'll still leave this open, since I'm sure I'll need to run higher vertex bakes later on one way or the other, and the crash issue persists. Unless that's just a flat hardware limitation that can't be circumvented, not sure!